# Matlab maximize function with parameters

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find a way to maximize function with parameters in Matlab. 
The function is similar to the following: `f = - t2*x(0)*(a(0) - 1) - t2*x(0)*(t1*a(0) + 1)*(a(1) - 1)`. I need to find `a(0)` and `a(1)` which will maximize `f`. `t1` and `t2` is nonnegative unknown parameters and `x(0) > 0` too. `a(0)` and `a(1)` may depend on `t1`, `t2`.

So generally I want to do the following using Matlab:
find some parameters which will `maximize(f)` where: some constraints are existing, and some parameters of `f` stays unknown.

I've tried `fminsearch` but in that case all parameters including `t1` and `t2` needs to be specified.

I wonder if such function exists in Matlab or it can be done some other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/). It an open source MATLAB based modeling package for convex optimization. It is slow, but it can help you as first approach

```
    cvx_begin
       variable a0
       variable a1 
       minimize( - t2*x0*(a0 - 1) - t2*x0*(t1*a0 + 1)*(a1 - 1)  )
       subject to
           t1 > 0
           t2 > 0
           x0 > 0
    cvx_end
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Actually this approach expects t1, t2, x0 to be defined (as fminsearch in Matlab). Also there are several rules regarding the function for minimization: it is impossible to work with the one from example (a0*a1 is forbidden).